# Working Tick Tuples suddenly stopping in Apache Storm

Tags: java, tuples, apache-storm

I am using Apache Storm version 2.4 for an application of mine which handles a lot of throughput. In my setup, I initialize a tick tuple like so: (java)

```
        topologyBuilder.setBolt(BOLT_A_KEY, new BoltA(config), config.getBoltAThreads())
            .fieldsGrouping(KINESIS_SPOUT_KEY, new Fields(KinesisRecordScheme.FIELD_PARTITION_KEY))
            .addConfiguration(TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, config.getBoltATickTupleTimeSeconds());
```

Most of the time works totally fine and as expected; however, at some point (say ~2 weeks?) I notice the topology totally stops and requires a redeploy. During my investigation as to what's going on, I found that the tick tuple totally stops which could potentially be the culprit (the stopping of the tick tuple would halt further executions for my particular application). I've looked into documentation around the tick tuple and found it pretty lacking.

My 2 questions then are:

1. Is it expected that the tick tuple would stop if back pressure from the spout became great enough? (I ask this to eliminate the chance that the tick tuple stopping is actually a side effect of the issue and not the root cause)
2. Why might the tick tuple stop working suddenly (and routinely) ?